# Use staff_member_required decorator, but without being redirected to the admin interface?

Tags: django, authentication, decorator

When I try to use staff_view, I get redirected in the admin authentication interface.

```
    from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

    @staff_member_required
    def staff_view(request..):
        ...
```

How can I make a custom login, and not getting redirected in the default admin login interface?

Comment: You'll have to write your own decorator :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use Django's [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_staff, login_url=reverse_lazy('foo'))
def staff_view(request..):
    ...
```

Answer (score 24):

It's worth pointing out that `staff_member_required` is a wrapper around `user_passes_test` (see [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py)) and it also accepts a `login_url` parameter, so you could do:

```
@staff_member_required(login_url=example_url)
def staff_view(request..):
    ...
```